# Characters different in RcURL/getURL than in browser

Tags: r, curl, xml-parsing, rcurl

I am looking to extract foreign-language text from a website. The following code (hopefully self-contained) will demonstrate the problem:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
agent="Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)" 
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt' ,useragent = agent,followlocation = TRUE , autoreferer = TRUE , curl = curl)

html <-getURL('http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/psearch/result12.aspx?dbsl=1008', maxredirs = as.integer(20), followlocation = TRUE, curl = curl)
work <- htmlTreeParse(html, useInternal = TRUE)
table <- xpathApply(work, "//table[@id = 'ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_DataList1' ]//font|//table[@id = 'ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_DataList1' ]//p", xmlValue) #this one captured some mess in 13
table[[2]]
```

Where the first bunch of characters in the console printout appear for me as `Â¸Ã\u0089Ã\u0092 iÃ\u0089{Ã\u0089xÃ\u0089 Ã\u008aÂºÃ\u0089EÃ²nÃ¹Â®Ãº`.

Note that if I go to the actual page (http://bit.ly/1AcE9Gs), and view the page source and find the second opening `<font` tag (corresponding to the second list item in my `table`, or inspect the element near the first Hindi characters) what renders in the page source looks something like this: `¸ÉÒ iÉ{ÉxÉ ÊºÉEònù®ú (nù¨Énù¨É):` which is what I want.

Anyone know why this might occur, and/or how to fix? Something to do with encodings in R, or RcURL? I can see all the way up to the initial `getURL` call that the characters are different like this, so it doesn't have to do with passing from the html text to `xpathApply`.

I am using MAC OSX 10.9.3, Chrome browser (for viewing the actual page), R 3.1.1.

If interested, see a related question on `xpathApply` here: [R and xpathApply -- removing duplicates from nested html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244084/r-and-xpathapply-removing-duplicates-from-nested-html-tags)

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem. What does `Encoding(html)` return? What does `Encoding(table[[2]])` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add encoding options to `htmlParse` and `getURL`:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
agent="Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)" 
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar = 'cookies.txt' ,useragent = agent,followlocation = TRUE , autoreferer = TRUE , curl = curl)

html <-getURL('http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/psearch/result12.aspx?dbsl=1008'
              , maxredirs = as.integer(20), followlocation = TRUE, curl = curl
              , .encoding = 'UTF-8')
work <- htmlParse(html, encoding = 'UTF-8')
table <- xpathApply(work, "//table[@id = 'ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_DataList1' ]//font|//table[@id = 'ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_DataList1' ]//p", xmlValue) #this one captured some mess in 13
> table[[2]]
[1] "¸ÉÒ iÉ{ÉxÉ ÊºÉEònù®ú (nù¨Énù¨É):\r\nºÉ¦ÉÉ{ÉÊiÉ ¨É½þÉänùªÉ, {É½þ±Éä ÊnùxÉ ¨ÉèÆ ¤ÉÉä±É\r\n®ú½þÉ lÉÉ iÉÉä ¨ÉèÆxÉä =iiÉ®ú {ÉÚ´ÉÒÇ ¦ÉÉ®úiÉ Eòä\r\n+ÉiÉÆEò´ÉÉnù {É®ú =ºÉ ÊnùxÉ nùÉä {É½þ±ÉÖ+ÉäÆ EòÉ =±±ÉäJÉ\r\nÊEòªÉÉ lÉÉ* +ÉVÉ ¦ÉÒ ¨ÉèÆ, ÊVÉºÉ EòÉ®úhÉ ºÉä +ÉiÉÆEò´ÉÉnù\r\n{ÉènùÉ ½þÖ+É, =ºÉEòä Ê´É¹ÉªÉ ¨ÉäÆ lÉÉäc÷É ºÉÉ =±±ÉäJÉ\r\nEò°üÆMÉÉ*"
```

Comment: Yes, this was it--I was fumbling with encoding in the getURL, but not in htmltreeparse--thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative implementation using rvest. Not only is the code simpler, but you don't have to do anything with the encoding, rvest figures it out for you.

```
library("rvest")
url <- "http://164.100.47.132/LssNew/psearch/result12.aspx?dbsl=1008"

search <- html(url)
search %>% 
  html_node("#ctl00_ContPlaceHolderMain_DataList1") %>%
  html_nodes("font, p") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  .[[2]]
#> [1] "¸ÉÒ iÉ{ÉxÉ ÊºÉEònù®ú (nù¨Énù¨É):\r\nºÉ¦ÉÉ{ÉÊiÉ ¨É½þÉänùªÉ, ...
```